# How to restore all the page information after logout using cookies on Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, cookies, iframe, selenium-chromedriver

After we click logout, the session expired and we can no longer use the store cookies to login the same user right? We are facing a situation where the same user would login to a system several times during the entire test suite, and we want to be able to restore all the page information that the user was on for various test case.

For example, User A login and navigate to page **(Page-10)** and then logout. After some time, User A login and navigate to page **(Page-14)** and then logout. Then, we want to be able to have the User A login and restore all the page information and direct the page to **Page-10** without going over all the navigation process.

Or just login to an user and have all the iframes I open on the previous login. Anyone has any idea on how to do that?

Comment: please provide your selenium version, which browser/Webdriver you are using.

Comment: For me this sounds like a question that has to be answered by the developers of the application under test. Clarify which cookies store information of previous sessions and then just save and send them in the next session.